# Reconstructing Markov chain from figure in R

Tags: markov-chains, information-theory, transition-matrix

I am trying to reconstruct a Markov process from Shannons paper "A mathematical theory of communication". My question concerns figure 3 on page 8 and a corresponding sequence (message) from that Markov chain from page 5 section (B). I used R to create a Markov chain, but important is only the transition matrix below (no answer on stackoverflow). I just wanted to check, if I have the right transition matrix to the figure from Shannons paper (I am new to this). I cannot post an image of the figure, so here is a link to Shannons paper: [https://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ectm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf)

Here is my transition matrix:

```
MessageTransitionMatrix = matrix(c(.4,.1,.2,.2,.1,
                                   .4,.1,.2,.2,.1,
                                   .4,.1,.2,.2,.1,
                                   .4,.1,.2,.2,.1,
                                   .4,.1,.2,.2,.1),
                                 nrow = 5,
                                 byrow = TRUE,
                                 dimname = list(MessageABCDE, MessageABCDE))
```

My goal was to also create a sequence (message) from that chain. I am mostly uncertain about the transition matrix, where infered the probabilities had to be all the same in every row to represent indipendence. The sequence though turned out ok, I guess:

```
> markovchainSequence(n = 20, markovchain = MCmessage, t0 = "A")
 [1] "D" "E" "A" "D" "A" "A" "B" "D" "E" "C" "A" "A" "E" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D"
[19] "A" "C"
```

Comment: Your question seems to be concerning the syntax of $\mathtt R$ as opposed to the actual mathematics involved here...but assuming you understand the latter, see e.g. for implementing the simulation: https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/simulating_discrete_chains_1.html

Comment: I sorted it out. Thanks! The upper transition matrix corresponds to the figure. Independent states and I think its called 0th order MC.

Comment: To be more precise, it is not the *states* that are independent, but rather the elements of any sample path generated by a finite-dimensional discrete-time Markov chain having a transition matrix with identical rows. (As can readily be verified by left-multiplying an arbitrary initial distribution with the transition matrix yields again one of said rows.)